# how to find the bottle neck in a bulk insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running a BULK INSERT in SQL Server for about 400,000, its taking between between thirty seconds and a couple minutes. The table I'm inserting in has PKs but no other index.

How can I test what the bottle neck is? Right now I'm just using `BULK INSERT 'table' from 'file' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a')` With all other arguments as default.

Would it be somehow faster to insert to a temporary table and then merge two sql tables? Or is there an argument I'm missing in `BULK INSERT` that could speed it up? Or is there a way to check that its just the disk speed slowing me down?

Comment: A trick we used to use long back was to remove/disable the PK and all indexes before the bulk operation, and recreate/enable them after the bulk operation.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but didn't gain enough time to compensate for recreating them after the insert (these tables are used as soon as the data is available)

Comment: Is the file in the same location as the database? Or is network traffic a possible bottle neck? BULK INSERT shouldn't take too long. You should also check for other workloads in the server at the time or any blocking in the destination table.

Answer (score 0):

Bulk Insert is the fastest way, hands down, to load data into SQL Server.  I believe 400k records is not too, too, too large.  However, it will take a little time, as you are seeing.  I'd guess 30-seconds to a couple minutes is not horrible performance.  What would you expect, honestly?

Comment: hoping to get it down to seconds. the hope was to investigate how to get there

Comment: The thing is, I don't think you get a lot of control or customization with the Bulk Insert.  As I know, it's kind of dumb.  It just takes a lot of data from a CSV file and dumps it into a table.  You sacrifice control and gain speed.  You can check out the link below.  I think these concepts were already highlighted in the discussion points listed above. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3434/options-to-improve-sql-server-bulk-load-performance/